# Lenovo Companion deleted contents of my Downloads folder

Tags: windows-10, data-recovery, lenovo-laptop, file-recovery

I own a Lenovo W530 laptop running Windows 10. Earlier today, I ran the Lenovo Companion app's Optimize tool which is a bit like Windows' Disk Cleanup function. I inadvertently included the Downloads folder (in the short list of folders) prior to clicking on Optimize, and that pretty much obliterated the contents of that folder! I happened to have a lot of precious content that I hadn't yet moved out of that folder, and now it is all gone!

Is there any way to recover the contents of this folder?! It is extremely important for me to get back the missing files.

Comment: it might be possible to recover data from hard drive, you should contact a professional, This is not something people can teach you here on super users

Answer (score 1):

Ouch. Have you tried the TestDisk (http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk_Step_By_Step) utility? It is completely free (no spyware / malware) and has an un-erase feature.

I suggest you pull the W10's drive immediately and slave it on another PC. There you can run TestDisk's un-erase feature on it and anything it can recover I suggest you save to a completely separate drive, not the W10's drive. The less writing done to the W10 drive the more you'll be able to recover.

Follow TestDisk's directions to a T and always select No Log at startup cuz it will chew up a hard drive's free space in just a few minutes!

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

In windows 10, you can recover previous versions of files and folders. Go to the downloads folder in explorer, right click, and select the 'Previous Versions' tab. If nothing listed you should immediately stop using your computer and take it to your local PC shop who will definitely be able to help you. Deleted files normally get replaced with other files fairly quickly so hopefully you have not downloaded any large items since the files disappeared.

You can use utilities but these cannot be effective when the main hard disk is being used. You need to boot from a WinPE based USB Stick/CDrom to use utilities like Testdisk and recuva with greater chance of success.